# Browser memory usage when appending tables to the DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, memory-management, html-table, memory-leaks

The code below is a snippet of how tables are created by JavaScript, including rows and cells, and then appended to the DOM to appear on the page.

Currently working with 4,000 rows across multiple tables and the memory usage for the page goes up to 1.6Gb!!

For the life of me I have not been able to see where this memory bulge is coming from.

I've tried extensively to narrow it down using the Chrome web tools like memory snapshots and performance tracking but I'm not well versed in reading that data.

```
function initGroupHeader(groupName, grpnum) {
   let tbl = createTableEle(groupName + "_jumpto", null, 'headertbl');
   let row = createTableRow();
   row.appendChild(doGroupNameCell(groupName)); //create a cell for the Group Name
   row.appendChild(createGrpHsCell(groupName)); //create hide/show sat link
   row.appendChild(createGrpSelDeCell(groupName)); //create hide/show sat link
   row.appendChild(createGrpPermCell(groupName, grpnum)); //create permit/deny etc links
   row.appendChild(createGrpAssGrpCell(grpnum, groupName)); //create assign group drop down
   row.appendChild(createGrpAssSwoCell(grpnum, groupName)); //create assign work order drop down
   row.appendChild(createGrpAdvLinkCell(groupName)); //create advanced link for the group
   tbl.appendChild(row);
    return tbl;
}
```

If the tables, rows, and cells are all created using `createElement()`.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. Happy to provide more information.

I should point out the table nodes that get appended are not stored in a global variable, it's local.